# Parsing Complex Mathematical Functions in Python

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, math, expression

Is there a way in Python to parse a mathematical expression in Python that describes a 3D graph? Using other math modules or not. I couldn't seem to find a way for it to handle two inputs.

An example of a function I would want to parse is [Holder Table Function](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/holder.html).

It has multiple inputs, trigonometric functions, and I would need to parse the abs() parts too.

I have two 2D numpy meshgrids as input for x1 and x2, and would prefer to pass them directly to the expression for it to evaluate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What form would your mathematical expression take? A string? Certainly, there is no built-in way. I've never heard of a library to do this either.

Comment: Yeah it would be a string. I saw Sympy had string parsing to symbols but I struggled to see stuff relating to multiple inputs

Comment: Did I do something wrong, since I'm getting downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote, but your question is very vague. You should give examples of input and expected output. It has a couple of close votes for being to broad. If you can give more specific examples the question will get more traction and a better reception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to write straight `numpy` code that evaluates this formula.

```
def holder(x1, x2):
    f1 = 1 - np.sqrt(x1**2 + x2**2)/np.pi
    f2 = np.exp(np.abs(f1))
    f3 = np.sin(x1)*np.cos(x2)*f2
    return -np.abs(f3)
```

Evaluated at a point:

```
In [109]: holder(10,10)
Out[109]: -15.140223856952055
```

Evaluated on a grid:

```
In [60]: I,J = np.mgrid[-bd:bd:.01, -bd:bd:.01]
In [61]: H = holder(I,J)
```

### Quick-n-dirty sympy

Diving into `sympy` without reading much of the docs:

```
In [65]: from sympy.abc import x,y
In [69]: import sympy as sp
In [70]: x
Out[70]: x
In [71]: x**2
Out[71]: x**2
In [72]: (x**2 + y**2)/sp.pi
Out[72]: (x**2 + y**2)/pi
In [73]: 1-(x**2 + y**2)/sp.pi
Out[73]: -(x**2 + y**2)/pi + 1
In [75]: from sympy import Abs
...
In [113]: h = -Abs(sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(y)*sp.exp(Abs(1-sp.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)/sp.pi)))
In [114]: float(h.subs(x,10).subs(y,10))
Out[114]: -15.140223856952053
```

Or with the sympify that DSM suggested

```
In [117]: h1 = sp.sympify("-Abs(sin(x)*cos(y)*exp(Abs(1-sqrt(x**2 + y**2)/pi)))")
In [118]: h1
Out[118]: -exp(Abs(sqrt(x**2 + y**2)/pi - 1))*Abs(sin(x)*cos(y))
In [119]: float(h1.subs(x,10).subs(y,10))
Out[119]: -15.140223856952053
...
In [8]: h1.subs({x:10, y:10}).n()
Out[8]: -15.1402238569521
```

### Now how do I use this with numpy arrays?

[Evaluating the result of sympy lambdify on a numpy mesgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830112/evaluating-the-result-of-sympy-lambdify-on-a-numpy-mesgrid)

```
In [22]: f = sp.lambdify((x,y), h1,  [{'ImmutableMatrix': np.array}, "numpy"])
In [23]: z = f(I,J)
In [24]: z.shape
Out[24]: (2000, 2000)
In [25]: np.allclose(z,H)
Out[25]: True
In [26]: timeit holder(I,J)
1 loop, best of 3: 898 ms per loop
In [27]: timeit f(I,J)
1 loop, best of 3: 899 ms per loop
```

Interesting - basically the same speed.

Earlier answer along this line: [How to read a system of differential equations from a text file to solve the system with scipy.odeint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676313/how-to-read-a-system-of-differential-equations-from-a-text-file-to-solve-the-sys)

Comment: typo: missing sqrt in expression

Comment: I might see if I can generalise it from that, the problem is it could be any expression that follows a similar format